# Custom Form after Rendered

Tags: 2013, custom-form, form, rendering

I'm trying to do a custom form and I using jquery to do some functionalities.
How could I know when the form finish rendering the fields?
I'm trying to use document ready from jquery but  this funtion triggers before the form finish rendering all the fields.

Is there another function i could use?

Comment: For 2013 look in to using JSLink and its PostRender event, like shown here: http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2014/js-link-highlighting-a-row-with-csr/ with a bit of luck you do not need a custom form at all, just add a JSLink file to it

Comment: I don't want to use a JSLink... I'm creating a form with SharePoint:FormField properties

Comment: I'm not talking about CSR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was a little of simple jquery...
I had to use

```
  $(window)load()
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready()
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: It sure looks like an answer too me! A short one, but still :)

Comment: Well @Waqas it wasn't a comment on the question it was just the answer to it

Comment: please mark this as answer, it is very short answer that's why i flag it.

Comment: I cannot mark it as an answer until 2 days...

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a js file using content editor web part and add the below code in it:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');

function init(){
 // perform functionalities here
}
```

Comment: This might works but i'm not working with normal forms... I'm working with custom forms associated to content types